# Forward usbmuxd (unix domain socket) to tcp socket

Tags: ios

When I use socat to forward /var/run/usbmuxd to tcp port:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:1234,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/usbmuxd
```

It will transfer all ios devices. Is there and way to transfer just one device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve this. You have asked a very specific question, so it probably helps if you provide more background as to what you're exactly trying to achieve.

Anyway, one thing you can do is to run launch an instance of usbmuxd which has access to only one iOS device. If you're on Linux, you can

- Run usbmuxd in a container, and make sure that container has only access to one iOS device
- Run usbmuxd in a VM, and attach only one iOS device to that VM.

Alternatively, you could write a program which intercepts all traffic to usbmuxd (e.g. a TCP proxy), and filters out any metion of iOS devices you don't want to share. For example, you could intercept the List command and make sure it returns only one iOS device. For an overview of the usbmuxd wire protocol, see libusbmuxd.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually i want to share my ios device via internet, but i just want to share only 1 device for 1 client. Can you tell me more about "intercepts all traffic to usbmuxd" ? Just how to connect to usbmuxd to intercepts.

Comment: @NhuNguyễn If you want to share 1 device for 1 client over the Internet, I'd think the better option may be to set up a dedicated VM or a Docker container to which you attach your USB device and to which your client connects. Barring that, you can write your own TCP server which implements the usbmuxd protocol, pretends to be usbmuxd. https://medium.com/@jon.gabilondo.angulo_7635/understanding-usbmux-and-the-ios-lockdown-service-7f2a1dfd07ae gives an overview of how that works.